# Error when plotting line graph using seaborn: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, linegraph

I am trying to make a more aesthetically pleasing graph for a project and was told that seaborn would make beautiful plots but I am having trouble with it as it returns the error: *If using all scalar values, you must pass an index*. I'm not sure why there is this error as I am able to plot a regular graph using the same dataframe.

This is the dataframe that I am using:
[image]

and I have successfully created a graph:

```
ax = data1.plot(xlabel='Year', ylabel='Electricity generation capacity', figsize=(15,10), marker='.')
ax.legend(title='Electricity generation capacity by Year', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

However, the graph is quite ugly as you can barely see the trend of the bottom three lines. (I do not know if seaborn will help with this issue as I am rather new to python and am unfamiliar with data visualization using python.)

Perhaps my code is wrong but when I try to make a graph, `sns.lineplot(data1)` , it returns an error as mentioned above.

Please let me know how I can solve this issue (Or if I can create a better-looking graph without seaborn, please teach me). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it seems like the Year is the dataframe index. Try this:

```
sns.lineplot (data=data1, x=data1.index)
```

Comment: The output is an empty graph and x-axis only shows 2005